# How to format Birth date to 'yyy-mm-dd' and calculate age from there

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I am currently working with a dataset for which i have to calculate the ages of the employees, however the format of the birth date is the following:
1987-05-17T00:00:00
How do I remove the 'T00:00:00' from the Birth date?

From there on I would like to calculate the age, which i tried to do in this way already:

```
FLOOR(DATE_DIFF(CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS DATE)), CAST(Birthdate AS DATE))) AS Age
```

However, when i keep getting the following error:

**Error: No matching signature for function DATE_DIFF for argument types: DATE. Supported signature: DATE_DIFF(DATE, DATE, DATE_TIME_PART) at [27:9]**

I think this error arises as a consequence of the weird date format to begin with. But im not entirely sure.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What data type is your field `birthdate`?  Why are you casting `CURRENT_DATE()` to be a `DATE` when it's already a `DATE`?  The error tells you that `DATE_DIFF()` takes a ***third*** parameter called `DATE_TIME_PART`; this is where you specify that you want the difference in years, which you are not doing.  `DATE_DIFF()` also returns an integer result, so there's no need for `FLOOR()`.  In short, I think you need to read the manual on how to use `DATE_DIFF()`?  Your brackets are also wrong; you have `DATE_DIFF( 
 CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS DATE)  )` as a single function call.

Comment: Hi @MatBailie, thank you for your response! 
I tried specifying the difference in years in the following way already (also getting rid of the FLOOR() and AS DATE() in the code like you said) in the following way: 

DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), CAST(Birthdate AS DATE)), 'year' AS Age

However, this gives me the same error again. 

the data type of birthdate is in DATETIME.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_diff

Comment: In your code snippet in the comments you have `'` around the `YEAR`, but that's incorrect if you look at the example I linked above.  Also, again, you have the brackets in the wrong place.  Try `DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), CAST(Birthdate AS DATE), YEAR)`

Comment: Wauw, it works now, thank you so much!!
 That was way more easy than I expected.

Comment: Read.  The.  Manual.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
FLOOR(DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00', Birthdate), YEAR)) AS Age
```

Comment: Just add a detail. As MatBailie already pointed out, "`DATE_DIFF()` also returns an integer result, so there's no need for `FLOOR()`".

Comment: totally agree, that was not a focus in here so I left it as in the original question in case if OP  had reason to have it :o)

Answer (score 0):

This is a query I use to calculate age in years, months and days:

```
SELECT 
username
,dob
,DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS years
,PERIOD_DIFF( DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m') , DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y%m') ) AS months
,DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dob) AS days
FROM users
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me in bigquery to get age

`FLOOR(DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), CAST(Birthdate AS DATE), day/365) AS Age`